# Set value of InstallDir in a function, or set auto populate value somehow?

Tags: nsis

I'm creating an installer using NSIS.  This installer actually installs two programs in two different directories in the same installer.  I am doing this using the modern user interface (MUI) pages and simply calling MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY twice specifying different starting parameteres, and capturing the directory in the LEAVE macro.  What I'm wondering is, can I somehow call InstallDir in a function, or set the auto directory populate value in a function?  Or possibly even call a function after the browse button has been returned from?

The reason I want to do this is so when the user clicks the browse button in either of the two directory pages, after they select a directory, the name of the finnal directory specifed in InstallDir will be appended.

For example: 
InstallDir value for program 1: c:\client
InstallDir value for program 2: c:\program files\server

user clicks browse on program 1 and chooses c:\temp the resulting path is c:\temp\client

user clicks browse on program 2 and chooses c:\whatever the resulting path is c:\whatever\server

For reference here are the code snipits of what I have that works, but does not deal with the auto append browse button behaviour:

```
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ClientDirectoryLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ServerDirectoryLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

; Setup the page display for the client install page
Function ShowPageClient
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Client" "Client"
  !insertmacro MUI_INNERDIALOG_TEXT 1006 "Client"

  ; setup intal directory
  Push $0
  StrCpy $0 $PROGRAMFILES 2 #
  ; CLIENT_FOLDER_NAME is defined as a folder, but this would basicaly
  ; result in C:\Client as the first 2 characters of $PROGRAMFILES
  ; is the hard drive with program files installed on it
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "$0\${CLIENT_FOLDER_NAME}"
  Pop $0

    ; set the inital value of the directory text box  
    !insertmacro MUI_INNERDIALOG_TEXT 1019 $INSTDIR

    ; find and disable the directory selection box 
    ; We do not want users to type in this box
    FindWindow $R0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
    GetDlgItem $R1 $R0 1019 ;Text Box
    EnableWindow $R1 0
FunctionEnd


; Setup the page display for the server install location page
Function ShowPageServer
  !insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Server" "Server"
  !insertmacro MUI_INNERDIALOG_TEXT 1006 "Server"

  ; setup intal directory
  ; SERVER_FOLDER_NAME is defined as a folder, but this would basicaly
  ; result in C:\Program Files\Server 
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "$PROGRAMFILES\${SERVER_FOLDER_NAME}"

  ; set the inital value of the directory text box  
  !insertmacro MUI_INNERDIALOG_TEXT 1019 $INSTDIR

  ; find and disable the directory selection box 
  ; We do not want users to type in this box
  FindWindow $R0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
  GetDlgItem $R1 $R0 1019 ;Text Box
  EnableWindow $R1 0

FunctionEnd
```

Note: I can make the browse button work for one of the directory pages, but then when I'm on the second page, the auto populate actual auto populates incorrectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay I finally figured it out. Basically there is a function that is called to "verify" the path after browse button is clicked. I tied into this function an appended the directory manual if needed. To do this I created a new variable and set it in a function called when the page is displays as follows:

```
; Client Directory
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW ShowPageClient
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE ClientDirectoryLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

; Setup the page display for the client install page
Function ShowPageClient
  ; setup intal directory
  Push $0
  StrCpy $0 $PROGRAMFILES 2 #
  StrCpy $INSTDIR "$0\${CLIENT_FOLDER_NAME}"
  Pop $0

  !insertmacro MUI_INNERDIALOG_TEXT 1019 $INSTDIR

  FindWindow $R0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
  GetDlgItem $R1 $R0 1019 ;Text Box
  EnableWindow $R1 0

  ; Setup the client or server variable to indicate that
  ; we're in the client install part to signal the .onVerifyInstDir function
  ; to put the correct directory
  StrCpy $CLIENT_OR_SERVER "client"
FunctionEnd
```

The function that is called after browse is .onVerifyInstDir so that is where I check the CLIENT_OR_SERVER variable and set the path appropriately

```
; This function is special and is called any time a
; path is validated on returning from the browse button
; need to append the correct directory if it does not already exists
; in the install directory path
Function .onVerifyInstDir
  ; save the current $0 register, as it is used in this function
  Push $0

  ${If} $CLIENT_OR_SERVER == "client"
    ; in the client stage so directory must contain CLIENT_FOLDER_NAME
    ${StrContains} $0 "${CLIENT_FOLDER_NAME}" "$INSTDIR"
    ${If} $0 == ""
      ; the install dir does not contain the folder so append it
      StrCpy $INSTDIR "$INSTDIR\${CLIENT_FOLDER_NAME}"
    ${EndIf}
  ${Else}
    ; in the server stage so directory must contain SERVER_FOLDER_NAME
    ${StrContains} $0 "${SERVER_FOLDER_NAME}" "$INSTDIR"
    ${If} $0 == ""
      ; the install dir does not contain the folder so append it
      StrCpy $INSTDIR "$INSTDIR\${SERVER_FOLDER_NAME}"
    ${EndIf}
  ${EndIf}

  ; pop the saved register value
  Pop $0
FunctionEnd
```

Couple notes:
the StrContains function I used was found here:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/StrContains

Further reference to the .onVerifyInstDir function can be found here:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.7.2.1.10

Answer (score 4):

The appended folder name is constant and set at compile time, there is a [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&group_id=22049&atid=373085&aid=1174184) related to this.

My advice is to abandon the append feature and let the user have full control over the two destinations:

```
Name "NSIS Test"
InstallDir ""
!include MUI.nsh
Var DirClient
Var DirServer

Function .onInit
;Set default destinations
StrCpy $DirClient "$ProgramFiles\$(^Name)\Client"
StrCpy $DirServer "$ProgramFiles\$(^Name)\Server"
FunctionEnd

!macro ConfigureMyDirPage type var
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VARIABLE ${var}
!define MUI_PAGE_HEADER_SUBTEXT "Choose the folder in which to install $(^NameDA) ${type}"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_TOP "Setup will install $(^NameDA) ${type} in the following folder. To install in a different folder, click Browse and select another folder. $_CLICK"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_TEXT_DESTINATION "${type} $(^DirSubText)"
!macroend

!insertmacro ConfigureMyDirPage "Client" $DirClient
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!insertmacro ConfigureMyDirPage "Server" $DirServer
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"

Section
DetailPrint DirClient=$DirClient
DetailPrint DirServer=$DirServer
SectionEnd
```